# Any means to allow differing counts of source/target parameters in a destructuring extractor

Tags: scala

Normal successful) case: correct number of target variables for destructuring:

```
scala> val arr = Array("aa","bb",1,2,3,4,5)
scala> val Array(a,b,one,two,three,four,five) = arr
a: Any = aa
b: Any = bb
one: Any = 1
two: Any = 2
three: Any = 3
four: Any = 4
five: Any = 5
```

Unsupported (?) Cases

a) Fewer target variables for the destructuring:  the intention would be to capture the "other" parameters into one Sequence-Like variable:

```
scala> val arr = Array("aa","bb",1,2,3,4,5)
arr: Array[Any] = Array(aa, bb, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val Array(a,b,one,two, others) = arr
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.Object;@146a8d2 (of class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
        at .<init>(<console>:12)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
```

b)  More target variables than source variables for the destructuring:  intention would be to have *optional* source variables

```
scala> val arr = Array("aa","bb",1,2,"optional-1","optional-2")
arr: Array[Any] = Array(aa, bb, 1, 2, optional-1, optional-2)

scala> val Array(a,b,one,two,optional1) = arr
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.Object;@151c590 (of class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
        at .<init>(<console>:12)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
```

Comment: You can bind the remaining parameters to a sequence using `_*`: `val Array(a, b, one, two, others @ _*) = arr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` has a deconstructing `::` operator which provides support for `a)`

```
scala> val l = List("aa","bb",1,2,"optional-1","optional-2")
l: List[Any] = List(aa, bb, 1, 2, optional-1, optional-2)

scala> val a :: b :: one :: two :: others = l
a: Any = aa
b: Any = bb
one: Any = 1
two: Any = 2
others: List[Any] = List(optional-1, optional-2)
```

The issue with providing this operator for other data structures in standard library is that other data structures do not have similar performance characteristics. Take a similarly defined operator against `Vector`.

```
object :#: {
  def unapply[A](a: Vector[A]): Option[(A, Vector[A])] =
    if (a.length > 1) Some(a(0) -> a.drop(1))
    else None
}

scala> val a :#: b :#: one :#: two :#: others = v
a: Any = aa
b: Any = bb
one: Any = 1
two: Any = 2
others: Vector[Any] = Vector(optional-1, optional-2)
```

I don't necessarily promote this, but you could define a similar operator which provides support for use case `b)`

```
object :?: {
  def unapply[A](l: List[A]): Option[(Option[A], List[A])] =
    l match {
      case Nil => Some(None -> Nil)
      case a :: tail => Some(Some(a) -> tail)
    }
}

scala> val l = List("aa","bb")
l: List[String] = List(aa, bb)

scala> val a :?: optional1 :?: optional2 :?: rest = l
a: Option[String] = Some(aa)
optional1: Option[String] = Some(bb)
optional2: Option[String] = None
rest: List[String] = List()
```

Comment: Ok i'll "buy" that one for answering the first part.

Comment: Actually on (a) I need the original data to be an array. Specifically it is the command line arguments that is Array[String].  But OK, we can do arr.toList as well.

Comment: I'm not sure pattern matching is the way to go here. You should check out [Scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt). For something quick and dirty, maybe.

Comment: that is useful.  AFA cmd line opts this time i resorted to a props file to contain optional features. But scopt looks useful for the future. in any case i will award. Consider an upvote.